# Jquery append while wrapping every x element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create HTML like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="el"></div>
      <div class="el"></div>
      <div class="el"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="el"></div>
      <div class="el"></div>
      <div class="el"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrap">
      <div class="el"></div>
      <div class="el"></div>
      <div class="el"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The component used to add `el` element:

```
<input type="text" name="elements" />
```

`el` elements will appended to the container based on what number is added in the input. Every 3 elements should be wrapped in `wrap` div.

What I have so far:

```
$("input[name=elements]").on("keydown keyup", function() {
   var amount = parseInt($(this).val());
   for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
     $(".container").append('<div class="el"></div>');
   }
});
```

It adds the `el` divs but I'm not sure how to simultaneously wrap every 3 in `wrap`. Also is it possible to also remove `el` divs? If say I first type `8` in the input then I type `3`, 11 divs will be added instead having just 3. In other words, the number of `el` divs in the HTML should alway be equal to the number in the input value. Would it make sense just to clear out the HTML first every time on input type?

Answer (score 0):

You could first create an array of elements based on number of input value, append it to container and then wrap every nth element into `wrap` element.

```js
const container = $('.container')

$("input").on('keyup', function() {
  const val = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
  const html = Array.from(Array(val), () => (
    $("<div>", {
      'class': 'el',
      'text': 'element'
    })
  ))

  container.html(html)

  for (let i = 0; i < val; i += 3) {
    container
      .find('.el')
      .slice(i, i + 3)
      .wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>");
  }
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div class="container"></div>
```